# Systemd DBus API returns service not loaded for disabled services

Tags: systemd, d-bus

I want to start a systemd service from its D-Bus interface. However, it seems that services that are not already started or "enabled" (running on startup) are unknown to the Systemd D-Bus interface :

```
# my-service.service
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my-service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
> systemctl status my-service
● my-service.service - My service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/my-service.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

> gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.systemd1 -o /org/freedesktop/systemd1 -m org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.GetUnit my-service.service
Erreur : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit my-service.service not loaded.

> systemctl enable my-service.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/my-service.service → /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/my-service.service.

> gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.systemd1 -o /org/freedesktop/systemd1 -m org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.GetUnit my-service.service
(objectpath '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/my_2dservice_2eservice',)
```

I can start my-service with systemctl, but I cannot access it via D-Bus.
How can I use the D-Bus interface as I can use `systemctl`, to start disabled services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [systemd D-Bus interface documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/#methods), there's the method `LoadUnit(name)` to get unit information and loading it from disk if not already.

Also it seems that the `StartUnit(name, mode)` method doesn't seems to indicate if it loads the unit but it would be a reasonable guess it does.

Comment: I'm not sure why `systemctl status` says that the service is loaded, it's misleading. But that seems to work. Thanks!